# Actions on Google - How to access

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

First time here (please be gentle).  I've built and had an action approved.  For the life of me, I cannot work out how to run it.

[Published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N3C2.png)

In simulation mode I got a test run to work on my google home.  However, my invocation doesn't run it, and I can't seem to find a portal to download it or similar.

[invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udR1y.png)

How do you people use it now that it has been approved?  I've checked my directory but there is no data.

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsQhM.png)

Comment: Users will be able to say "Talk to X" to activate it. It may take a day or two for it to be available.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Don't forget to take the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find how to get the most out of the site.

Comment: It was published on the second of Jan, but the 'talk to' invocation still isn't working

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to use the same invocation phrases that you used for testing in the simulator.

Although it is "published", it does take time to be distributed to all of Google's servers and for it to be available on everyone's Assistant. There isn't any way you can rush this process - it usually takes a couple of days.

You can look at your Action Console, click on "Analytics" on the left, and then the "Directory" tab on top to see how it appears in the directory.

[image]

If you view the directory URL from a mobile device, you can also invoke the Action from the directory entry itself once it is available.

You will never "download" or "install" it on a Google Home. Think of it as a website and your Google Home as a browser.

Comment: You also got an email about the action being published (right?) and in that email you have a link to your action directory page. This page contain all the information about your action, including the invocations phrases.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  

My action has been published since Jan [link](https://ibb.co/mymPyb) I have an invocation [link](https://ibb.co/dGZBdb), but my directory is empty [link](https://ibb.co/demeWw)

Comment: Here's the directory entry: https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/0000000725ceabe9?hl=en-US I was able to get to it on some of my devices, so its definitely out there. I think the biggest problem, for me, was that I had no clue how to pronounce "BIM".